# Django jinja values not passed in correctly to iframe url (open streetmap)

Tags: django, iframe, jinja2, openstreetmap

I have tried several ways to incorporate an openstreetmap via iframe into my django app. I can see the map fine and can zoom in or out, but it is always a map of Antigua. I want to embed a small map in my django template and pass in latitude and longitude from jinja. It makes no difference whether I pass in hard coded lon and lat or jinja, I still get the same map in openstreetmaps.

I started with this template from the openstreetmaps wiki https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLinkMap :

`<iframe width="420" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.openlinkmap.org/small.php?lat=<LAT>&lon=<LON>&zoom=<ZOOM>" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>`

No matter whether I hard code or put dynamic values, I see a map of Antigua. I tried passing in the parameters from jinja:

`<iframe width="420" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.openlinkmap.org/small.php?lat={{ li.latitude }}&lon={{ li.longitude }}&zoom=10" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>`

That didn't work, so I tried just typing in the long and lan, and I still get Antigua:

But the following works fine as a url link and passes in the correct parameters:

`<a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=12/{{ li.latitude }}/{{ li.longitude }}" target="_blank"><b>View Larger Map</b></a>`

I am new to openstreetmaps, django, and jinja and cannot see where I am making an error.

Answer (score 1):

You must write as follows:

```
{{ li.latitude|safe }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found that using the `<embed>` tag worked fine. Seems `<iframe>` is not always supported in html5 and that was causing some problems perhaps.